# Pandas Working with large - hmda data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to work with the [following data](http://files.consumerfinance.gov/hmda/hmda_lar-2012.csv.gz), but continue to have memory errors.

If I were able to read in the entire csv, I would be able to answer questions like the total count of items per `action_taken_name` by doing something like:

```
df = pd.pread_csv('path/to/my_file.csv')
df.groupby('action_taken_name').agg({'action_taken_name':'count'})
```

Given the memory constraint, what would be the smartest way to approach this?

I continue to run into various issues and feel there must be a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read_csv has a couple of ways that could help. Either usecols to only select the necessary columns, or use chunksize to look at it in parts.